# Link click does nothing after ajax switching?

Tags: php, html, ajax

An odd case I'm trying to figure out here.  I'm trying to design a mailbox system, and making some of the options ajax-y.  Here's the scenario:

We have a page with 2 tabs, inbox and compose.  Inbox is a essentially a list of links of the form mailbox.php?msg=xxx.  Clicking on the inbox or compose tabs does an ajax switch.

So, let's say we're on an message page:
mailbox.php?msg=123

I click on "compose" - it ajax switches to a compose form.  I change my mind, click on "inbox" - it goes back to a list of messages.

Note, the url has not changed at this point (all has been done through ajax).

I click on the same message as before. It should go back into that message.  However, nothing happens!  The url it should go to (mailbox.php?msg=123) IS the url showing in the address bar, but, due to the earlier ajax activity, it's showing the inbox.

Thoughts on how to resolve this?  And, out of curiosity, an explanation?  Normally, clicking on a link that takes you to a page you're already on will reload the page.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing that I can think of!!! which browser are you using? can you make sure that same result is in another browser as well?

Comment: Seeing it both in FF3.6 and IE8 . . .

Comment: One more thing you can check is the links itself on the mails after the AJAX request. Try using firebug to see if they are all right. Another debug point will be any javascript errors that are being hidden. Let know how it goes. It piqued my interest :)...

Comment: Ah!  I think it's because the link has an anchor tag on it.

Comment: yay!! so it was the older ajax request then... thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - this had to do with anchor tag showing up in the URL in some cases.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you may need to re-bind the event handlers, I think there's a function jquery.live that does this?